# separate application.properties from .war for tomcat container

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, war

When I use executable `.jar` for my project, I can put my `application.properties` file into same folder as my `.jar`, and all my property values will be reading from extended `application.properties` file.

**My question is:** It is possible to make like this for `.war` and `tomcat` server?

[UPDATE]

**The answer is:** On standalone tomcat you would have to put an `application.properties` in `<tomcat>/bin`

Thanks to @Strelok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run your application with `spring.config.location` property set to the path to your properties file using the `file:` protocol:

```
# will look for /etc/myapp/application.properties
-Dspring.config.location=file:/etc/myapp/

# will look for /etc/myapp/custom.properties
-Dspring.config.location=file:/etc/myapp/custom.properties
```

Default config locations that are always searched:

1. file:./config/
2. file:./
3. classpath:/config/
4. classpath:/

There is a lot more info in the [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) section of the documentation for Spring Boot.

Comment: if spring checked `file:/` (same folder as `.war`) why when i put my config there (inside `tomcat` server), my app still gets data from compiled config (inside `.war`)? But for executable `.jar` it works fine

Comment: Tomcat runs the application from and `exploded war` folder, not directly from the war file.

Comment: if i put my `app.war` into `webapps` where i should put `application.properties` file?

Comment: On standalone tomcat you would have to put it in `<tomcat>/bin`. That's why I said it is MUCH better if you just provide a custom `-Dspring.config.location` value.

Comment: i was add `spring.config.location=file:/Applications/server/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/webapps/` to my `application.properties` and rebuild app and deploy it. Was put `application.properties` to `/Applications/server/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/webapps/` (absolute path) - and nothing again. Is that mean what path is incorrect? I mean, path should begin from `<tomcat>` folder?

Comment: was put `application.properties` into `<tomcat>/bin` it's work now! Thanks @Strelok

Answer (score 1):

Refer Tomcat Class loader for your version of Tomcat to understand what all class loaders are available. Depending upon that, you can add your application properties files to Shared or Common class loader by keeping it in appropriate directory and adding that directory into the class loader entry in `catalina.properties` file. Tomcat 7 documentation does not show shared classloader, but `catalina.properties` does have a placeholder for that. If shared works, go for that instead of common [Tomcat 7 Classloader](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

Comment: u mean i can put my `application.properties` into any folder, add path to this folder to `catalina.properties` file and tomcat will read my env properties from my config?

Comment: Yes right. Check catalina.properties, there will be placeholders like `shared.loader=` and `common.loader`. Prefer to use `shared.loader` and fall back to `common.loader` if shared does not work. Please do not change `server.loader`.